# How to make this simple recurrence relationship (difference equation) tail recursive?

Tags: f#, tail-recursion

```
let rec f n =
    match n with
    | 0 | 1 | 2 -> 1
    | _ -> f (n - 2) + f (n - 3)
```

Without CPS or Memoization, how could it be made tail recursive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let f n = Seq.unfold (fun (x, y, z) -> Some(x, (y, z, x + y))) (1I, 1I, 1I)
          |> Seq.nth n
```

Or even nicer:

```
let lambda (x, y, z) = x, (y, z, x + y)
let combinator = Seq.unfold (lambda >> Some) (1I, 1I, 1I)
let f n = combinator |> Seq.nth n
```

To get what's going on here, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35940/elegant-snippets-of-f/3763473#3763473) snippet. It defines Fibonacci algorithm, and yours is very similar.

*UPD* There are three components here:

1. The **lambda** which gets `i`-th element;
2. The **combinator** which runs recursion over `i`; and
3. The **wrapper** that initiates the whole run and then picks up the value (from a triple, like in @Tomas' code).

You have asked for a tail-recursive code, and there are actually two ways for that: make your own combinator, like @Tomas did, or utilize the existing one, `Seq.unfold`, which is certainly tail-recursive. I preferred the second approach as I can split the entire code into a group of `let` statements.

Answer (score 4):

The solution by @bytebuster is nice, but he does not explain how he created it, so it will only help if you're solving this specific problem. By the way, your formula looks a bit like Fibonacci (but not quite) which can be [calculated analytically without any looping](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibFormula.html) (even without looping hidden in `Seq.unfold`).

You started with the following function:

```
let rec f0 n = 
  match n with 
  | 0 | 1 | 2 -> 1 
  | _ -> f0 (n - 2) + f0 (n - 3)
```

The function calls `f0` for arguments `n - 2` and `n - 3`, so we need to know these values. The trick is to use [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) (which can be done using memoization), but since you did not want to use memoization, we can write that by hand.

We can write `f1 n` which returns a three-element tuple with the current and two past values values of `f0`. This means `f1 n = (f0 (n - 2), f0 (n - 1), f0 n)`:

```
let rec f1 n = 
  match n with 
  | 0 -> (0, 0, 1)
  | 1 -> (0, 1, 1)
  | 2 -> (1, 1, 1)
  | _ -> 
    // Here we call `f1 (n - 1)` so we get values
    //   f0 (n - 3), f0 (n - 2), f0 (n - 1)
    let fm3, fm2, fm1 = (f1 (n - 1))
    (fm2, fm1, fm2 + fm3)
```

This function is not tail recurisve, but it only calls itself recursively *once*, which means that we can use the accumulator parameter pattern:

```
let f2 n =
  let rec loop (fm3, fm2, fm1) n = 
    match n with 
    | 2 -> (fm3, fm2, fm1)
    | _ -> loop (fm2, fm1, fm2 + fm3) (n - 1)
  match n with
  | 0 -> (0, 0, 1)
  | 1 -> (0, 1, 1)
  | n -> loop (1, 1, 1) n
```

We need to handle arguments `0` and `1` specially in the body of `fc`. For any other input, we start with initial three values (that is `(f0 0, f0 1, f0 2) = (1, 1, 1)`) and then loop n-times performing the given recursive step until we reach 2. The recursive `loop` function is what @bytebuster's solution implements using `Seq.unfold`.

So, there is a tail-recursive version of your function, but only because we could simply keep the past three values in a tuple. In general, this might not be possible if the code that calculates which previous values you need does something more complicated.

Comment: The explanation is actually an algebraic simplification of `f2` in your code, considering the fact that `lambda(n)` is the Nth element of the infinite sequence of `lambda(i)`'s.

Answer (score 3):

Better even than a tail recursive approach, you can take advantage of matrix multiplication to reduce any recurrence like that to a solution that uses O(log *n*) operations.  I leave the proof of correctness as an exercise for the reader.

```
module NumericLiteralG =
    let inline FromZero() = LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
    let inline FromOne() = LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne

// these operators keep the inferred types from getting out of hand
let inline ( + ) (x:^a) (y:^a) : ^a = x + y
let inline ( * ) (x:^a) (y:^a) : ^a = x * y

let inline dot (a,b,c) (d,e,f) = a*d+b*e+c*f
let trans ((a,b,c),(d,e,f),(g,h,i)) = (a,d,g),(b,e,h),(c,f,i)
let map f (x,y,z) = f x, f y, f z

type 'a triple = 'a * 'a * 'a
// 3x3 matrix type
type 'a Mat3 = Mat3 of 'a triple triple with
    static member inline ( * )(Mat3 M, Mat3 N) = 
        let N' = trans N
        map (fun x -> map (dot x) N') M
        |> Mat3
    static member inline get_One() = Mat3((1G,0G,0G),(0G,1G,0G),(0G,0G,1G))
    static member (/)(Mat3 M, Mat3 N) = failwith "Needed for pown, but not supported"

let inline f n =
    // use pown to get O(log n) time
    let (Mat3((a,b,c),(_,_,_),(_,_,_))) = pown (Mat3 ((0G,1G,0G),(0G,0G,1G),(1G,1G,0G))) n
    a + b + c

// this will take a while...
let bigResult : bigint = f 1000000
```